# how to make dynamic xaml in silverlight

Tags: dynamic, silverlight-3.0

Good day! 
I want to make a form - a set of questions with different answer types:
some questions have a number of answers and you can check one of the answers using radiobutton, other questions you should answer using a textbox, some answers have a datetime type and you choose answer for them using a DatePicker and so on. 
I get all information about the questions and answer types from a WCF service.

I want to make this form using making a dynamic xaml but i've naver made dynamic xaml and I don't know exactly how to make it.

Please, can you give me a council about dynamic xaml or maybe you have any other ideas about how to make this form?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following article and linked video to get an idea of dynamically creating UI elements 
http://jesseliberty.com/2008/05/05/creating-controls-in-code/